# Why there is el-api.jar in Tomcat7 but no jstl libs?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el, tomcat7

Where one should normally take JSTL/EL libraries? Does Tomcat distribution should include them? I have installed Tomcat7 for use under Eclipse Indigo and now see under "Apache Tomcat v7.0" branch in Project explorer, that there is a jar named `el-api.jar`. How it realtes with `jstl-api.jar` and `jstl-impl.jar` I usually used to have JSTL/EL in my jsps? Can I use EL or JSTL in my jsps having only `el-api.jar` installed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tomcat is a Servlet and JSP container. The Expression Language is a dependency of the [JSP specification](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=245). JSTL is not.

From the release notes:

> **Bundled APIs:**
>
> A standard installation of Tomcat 7.0 makes all of the following APIs
>   available for use by web applications (by placing them in "lib"):
>
> - annotations-api.jar (Annotations package)
> - catalina.jar (Tomcat Catalina implementation)
> - catalina-ant.jar (Tomcat Catalina Ant tasks)
> - catalina-ha.jar (High availability package)
> - catalina-tribes.jar (Group communication)
> - ecj-3.7.1.jar (Eclipse JDT Java compiler)
> - el-api.jar (EL 2.2 API)
> - jasper.jar (Jasper 2 Compiler and Runtime)
> - jasper-el.jar (Jasper 2 EL implementation)
> - jsp-api.jar (JSP 2.2 API)
> - servlet-api.jar (Servlet 3.0 API)
> - tomcat-api.jar (Interfaces shared by Catalina and Jasper)
> - tomcat-coyote.jar (Tomcat connectors and utility classes)
> - tomcat-dbcp.jar (package renamed database connection pool based on Commons DBCP)

Since JSTL is just a tag library, you should be able to add any implementation by placing it in your application's `WEB-INF/lib`.

- [java.net implementation](http://jstl.java.net/)

Comment: So I can use EL without JSTL? Just put it into JSP?

Comment: Yes. {fill minimum character limit}

Comment: Does your links should contain TLD files?

Comment: It appears that Apache don't maintain a JSTL 1.2 implementation (though it makes me wonder what they ship in Geronimo.) The Glassfish jstl-impl.jar should contain the TLD files under the META-INF/ path.